# Exception occurred calling method NotesDocument.send(boolean, string) null

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

This is code I am using in Button Click Event on SSJS:

```
try{   
 var doc:NotesDocument = currentDocument.getDocument();
 doc.send(false,"tuser1@gmail.com");
  }
  catch(e)
  { 
  sessionScope.Err123=e
  }
```

This is an error I am getting :

```
    message Exception occurred calling method NotesDocument.send(boolean, string) null
```

Please help, I am not able to send a mail in ssjs on xpages.

Comment: Please edit your question to add [**sample data**](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. Provide them as [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and strictly [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **DO NOT** post code or additional information in comments. Please ensure you have a [**minimal, complete and verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This sounds very similar to your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46262769/xpage-mime-mail-send-error-method-notesdocument-send-null. Check the XPages log files in the IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT folder for a detailed description of the null pointer exception and let us know what the error is. The XPages Log File Reader application from OpenNTF.org can help you with easy access to the log files.